# Autorotation code fails

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6

I have the following code to prevent a view from autorotating. But in IOS 6 it is not working. What should I do?

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
// pre-iOS 6 support
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

Comment: In which view controller is this code? Is this view controller inside a container controller (a custom one, or an `UITabbarController`, `UINavigationController` or `UISplitViewController`)?

Comment: If this is in a custom view controller buried in a hierarchy, the view detecting the rotation will need to pass the message down the chain.

Comment: Have you set the "Supported Interface Orientations" in the "target page"?

Comment: Inside a UINavigationController